# Get live html feed from website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

When a webpage like https://poloniex.com/exchange#btc_eth is opened in the browser, we see that the browser constantly shows updated buy and sell orders. Also, in the Elements section in the chrome console, these updates are visible in the HTML tables.

Is there a way I can use a nodejs script run on my pc (so not in the browser console) to get these live html table updates from that website, without having to do a GET request every time?

If the chrome browser is able to do it, nodejs / jQuery / ajax should be able to do it as well. I tried the XMLHttpRequest nmp module but no luck yet.

Comment: You would use their [api](https://poloniex.com/support/api/)

Comment: @James I just used this website as an example. I would like to have this functionality for any website that has a live data feed. Not exchanges per se.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible they are using token authentication which means you wouldn't be able to get all the connection info you need just from their client-side code. Have you downloaded it and looked at it yet?

If you find it's not possible to call their services, there are other free products designed for webscraping. AutoHotKey is one that can open a web page and traverse its DOM. I believe it has the ability to run in the background, but don't quote me.